# PageSpeed Insights icomoon font recommendation

Tags: pagespeed

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsharktoy.dev.cooa.la%2Fhome%2Fen%2F_all123&tab=mobile advises to use link rel for icomoon.ttf. But I can't just add **link rel="preload"** because it's included through import directive in another css file.

Adding **font-display: swap;** doesn't help too (as mentioned in https://invisioncommunity.com/forums/topic/447420-font-icomoon-delay/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can either remove reference of the font link from that css
  resources and directly call from your html file, like this

  < link rel="preload" href="http://www.pagespeedinsights.org/theme/css/normalize.css" as="style">
  or
- Remove the tiff reference from the css entirly since .woff font format is
  enough and is supported by all modern broswers.

Comment: If I declare fonts with <link rel="preload" href="icomoon.woff" as="font"> directly in my html page, then all the fonts with rel="preload" are loaded. So, the page size increases.

Comment: If I add link="preload" to css file, the warning remains the same, because fonts are still imported.